# Debugging x64 application (C++) using visual studio 2012

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging

I have a visual studio 2012 C++ application which compiles and run, but doesn't stop on breakpoints.

I already installed remote debugger (x64) and also run it and configure it for remote debugging.

In visual studio I tried boith remote debug and local debug, but both of them generate same result. It doesn't stop at breakpoints.

What do I do to debug a x64 c++ application?

**Edit 1**

Just found that the debugger says:

```
Symbol loading for myapp.exe was skipped because it is not specified in the includes modules
```

What that means?

Comment: You're building in debug mode, right?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit yes: The configuration is debug. Should I do anything else?

Comment: Are you sure the breakpoint is reachable?

Comment: @C.Lang It is on the first line on winmain so I believe they should be reachable.

Comment: Do you have a constructor for a global variable?  Some things are run before main.

Comment: @IraBaxter No, it is an old code and written in c mode so there is no class or something such this.

Comment: Do you have installed Cisco VPN software? It looks is not related, but I know there are an issue with VS2012 and that software installed.

Comment: @Gonmator No I don't have it installed

Comment: Do you start the program with "Start debugging"? After you start does it print to the output the symbols loaded/not found for .EXE and dlls? If you run and use Break All does it point to source?

Comment: and check out stuff here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/4c8f14c9%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: While the debugger message was intended to warn you that you'll have a problem, it doesn't make any sense as posted.  The term "includes modules" is meaningless.  If you translated it from a non-English message then post the original message exactly as shown to you so we'll have a shot at interpreting its actual meaning.

Comment: I don't know, what you doing, but I have an idea. For project building use F7, for launching in debug mode F5 or F11 (building must be set into debug mode).
F5 goes to the first breakpoint;
F11 goes to the first line of executing code line.
I'm not sure if you did things in this way, I hope it was helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After checking project and build configuration, I found that the Generate debug info in debug part of linker

(Linker ->Debug: generate debug info)

is blank.

After setting it to yes, the debugger starts to work!