# Debugging x64 Unit Tests in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, unit-testing, 64-bit, visual-studio-2013

I am having difficulty debugging C++ x64 unit tests in Visual Studio 2012/13.

My unit test project builds perfectly, for both Win32 and x64, but when debugging a test the symbols are loaded but the breakpoints set are skipped completely and the program never pauses, much like what happens if you just run the test.

If I build the unit test project for Win32, the breakpoints are hit and I can debug as usual.

Are there any special settings for debugging unit tests in x64? The properties were copied from the default Win32 settings for the project, and all win32-specific options were removed. Is this the correct idea for configuring a unit test project?

Comment: Might be something for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17317601/debugging-x64-application-c-using-visual-studio-2012

Comment: @DavidBrabant Thanks for the suggestion but Debug Info was already being generated for both the Win32 and x64 builds.

Comment: I just fixed same problem. It looks like **Debugging** -> **Command** value in project settings matters some how. I just deleted **UnitTests.vcxproj.user** and I was able to debug tests.

Answer (score 2):

You have to set the Test runner's default processor architecture to x64. You can find this in Test | Test Settings | Default Processor Architecture | x64.

You can also create a test settings file with this setting in it.

- Add an XML file to your Visual Studio solution and rename it so that its file extension is .runsettings.
- Replace the file content with the example.
- Edit it to your own needs.
- On the Test menu, choose Test Settings, Select Test Settings File.

Taken from [Configuring Unit Tests by using a .runsettings File](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj635153.aspx)

You want to change the `TargetPlatform` flag as noted below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RunSettings>
  <RunConfiguration>
    <ResultsDirectory>.\TestResults</ResultsDirectory>
    <TargetPlatform>x86</TargetPlatform>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>Framework40</TargetFrameworkVersion>
  </RunConfiguration>
  <!-- more stuff -->
</RunSettings>
```

Comment: This did not resolve the same issue for me.  Using xunit with C# and visual studio, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

### Under Visual Studio 2017:

I couldn't say why the behavior was different under x86; but under 64-bit Windows, at least, the unit tests build as a DLL that is **run by a separate test execution runner**.  You can see this by looking in Visual Studio's `Test` menu, under `Settings` you'll see a menu item referring to it.  Since tests are not normally run through Visual Studio, any breakpoints you set are irrelevant.

The key is there, in the same `Test` menu: you'll find a `Debug` submenu, allowing you to debug "selected" or "all" tests.  If you run the test that way, your breakpoints should hit within Visual Studio.